# Problem with passing boolean - VBA ADODB Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, stored-procedures, adodb

Trying to execute Oracle stored procedure using ADODB. Had no issues until  boolean was added to procedure. I think the issue is with CreateParameter adBoolean DataTypeEnum.

Error: wrong number or types of arguments in call WEIGH_PACKAGE_PR

Oracle

```
PROCEDURE WEIGH_PACKAGE_PR
    (in_action_code         IN NUMBER,
     in_pass_num            IN NUMBER,
     in_cont_no             IN VARCHAR2,
     in_scale_id            IN VARCHAR2,
     in_current_user        IN NUMBER,
     in_bypassnumber        IN NUMBER,
     in_override_tarewt     IN BOOLEAN)
```

VBA

```vb
With db
  If .state = adStateClosed Then
   .ConnectionString = conStr
   .CursorLocation = adUseClient
   .Open
  End If
End With

With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = db
  .NamedParameters = True
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandText = "COMMON_SCALES_PK.WEIGH_PACKAGE_PR"
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_action_code", adBigInt, adParamInput, , 1)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_pass_num", adBigInt, adParamInput, , 1)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_cont_no", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "I658638002")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_scale_id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6, "T05R02")
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_current_user", adBigInt, adParamInput, , 3737)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_bypassnumber", adBigInt, adParamInput, , Null)

  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_override_tarewt", adBoolean, adParamInput, 1, False)

 Set rst = .Execute()

End With
```

Comment: just a shot in the dark but replace `False` with `0`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman tried it. No go.

Comment: `CBool("False")`? The key seems to be to get the VBA boolean to translate to the psql boolean. Also are you sure you are calling the correct database? For example, if you are added the boolean in a dev version of the database but are calling the prod version in excel and that has not been updated, that could produce the error message you got.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman just tried CBool("False"). No go. Nothing has changed except adding the boolean to proc. Been adding one parameter at a time because having issue executing 32 params at once. Up to in_override_tarewt.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman development database. No production database in the mix, yet.

Comment: The thing that stood out to me as being odd is that you have the length of the adBoolean defined as 1.  Have you tried removing this, or extending it to 6 so False can fit?

Comment: @ShaunPeterson tired this as well. No go. I don't remember having any issues in .NET.

Comment: I think instead of `Null` you should better use `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Oracle 12.1 it was not possible to use PL/SQL data types as bind values, see [Changes in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-57E439FB-B196-46CB-857C-0ADAB32D9EA0)

Also the ADODB driver must support such data types.

You did not tell us neither which Oracle version you use nor which ADODB driver. If you still use the ancient Microsoft provider `MSDAORA` then for sure it does not work with BOOLEAN values.

Comment: I am using MSDORA and Oracle 11.  ADODB does support adBoolean data type but it must be the provider. I changed to  OraOLEDB.Oracle and OraClient12Home1, still no good.  We decided to default the boolean parameter passing null and derive value on database side. .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_override_tarewt", adBoolean, adParamInput, Null). Thanks.

Comment: It must be also supported by the database. I doubt that you upgraded the database that quickly.